# Graph QL, what does "on" do for a Fragment

Tags: graphql

I am looking at GraphQL but am confused why when using a fragment as below, you have to define the "on Character"? could this be anything any name as doesn't explain or have the context on the GraphQL documentation.

```
query {
  leftComparison: hero(id: "1") {
    ...comparisonFields
  }
  rightComparison: hero(id: "2") {
    ...comparisonFields
  }
}

fragment comparisonFields on Character {
  name
  appearsIn
  friends {
    name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [the example on graphql.org](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) doesn't make this totally obvious, [a fragment is always attached to some specific type](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Type-Conditions) (can be an object type, interface, or union).  Inside the fragment, you can only use fields that exist on the type that's named; the server will check this for you (and clients are capable of checking ahead of time if they want to).

If a field returns an interface or union type, you can similarly only select fields that you know to exist (because an interface provides them), but you can attempt to match on specific types that implement the interface or are members of the union to get more data.  This is frequently done with [inline fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments), but since a named fragment is attached to a type, you can use named fragments as well.  If the schema contains the very generic query

```graphql
interface Node { id: ID! }
type Query {
  node(id: ID!): Node
}
```

and `Character` implements `Node`, then you can plug in the named fragment you have here

```graphql
query GetCharacterDetails($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ...comparisonFields
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok So the hero object would use a "Character" interface in this example? Character would be an interface. Shame they didn't specify this if that is the case.

Comment: `... on Hero` should work fine too; the spec allows both concrete (object) types and interfaces (and also unions).